# Should I use api.mydomain.com or mydomain.com/api/ for my API?

Tags: web-server, domain

Im developing a web-based application, using Angular2 as front-end and Django 1.10 as back-end, and Nginx as web-servers interface.

Should Angular2 access the Django API through `api.mydomain.com` or `mydomain.com/api/`?

I have seen examples of both, and I want to know the pros and cons.

Answer (score 2):

I generally prefer using `api.example.com` instead of a URL path. Doing this allows you to de-couple your web application infrastructure from your API infrastructure. Perhaps they're running on the same server now, but by using a sub-domain, you can easily separate them in the future without requiring major code changes.